# How can i train deeplabv3+ with detectron2 on coco dataset?

Tags: image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, deeplab

I need to train deeplabv3+ with detectron2 on coco instance segmentation dataset. I can train maskrcnn model on coco with detectron, but I could not use deeplab (detectron/projects/deeplab). Is there anyone who trained deeplab using detectron2 before?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The DeepLab architecture is for semantic segmentation, not instance segmentation. I don't think it's possible to use any of the DeepLab architectures in detectron on the COCO instance segmentation dataset.